# Separate duplicates and output to other worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I tried to make a program that separates the duplicates and outputs to other worksheets. The data is composed of 3 columns and thousands of rows. First column is a unique number, second column is the material name, and third is the description of the material.

I tried:

```
Sub duplicates_separation()

    Dim duplicate(), i As Long
    Dim delrange As Range, cell As Long
    Dim delrange2 As Range

    Dim shtIn As Worksheet, shtOut As Worksheet
    Set shtIn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("process")
    Set shtOut = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("output")

    x = 2
    y = 1

    Set delrange = Range("b1:b30000")  'set your range here
    Set delrange2 = Range("c1:c30000")

    For cell = 1 To delrange.Cells.Count
        If Application.CountIf(delrange, delrange(cell)) > 1 Then
            ReDim Preserve duplicate(i)
            duplicate(i) = delrange(cell).Address
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    For i = UBound(duplicate) To LBound(duplicate) Step -1
        Range(duplicate(i)).Value = shtOut.Cells(x, 1).Value
        x = x + 1
    Next i

End Sub
```

But it goes to `Error 9, Out of Range`. It worked before, I don't know why it goes to an error. Anybody know why?

UPDATE

error happen in `For i = UBound(duplicate) To LBound(duplicate) Step -1`

what i chaged :
from
`range(duplicate(i)).entirerow.cut
shtout.cells(x,1).paste`

to

`Range(duplicate(i)).Value = shtOut.Cells(x, 1).Value`

---

**UPDATE** It's works now!

```
Sub duplicates_separation()

    Dim duplicate(), i As Long
    Dim delrange As Range, cell As Long
    Dim delrange2 As Range

Dim shtIn As Worksheet, shtOut As Worksheet
      Set shtIn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("process")
    Set shtOut = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("output")

    x = 2
    y = 1

    Set delrange = shtIn.Range("b1:b30000")  'set your range here
   Set delrange2 = shtIn.Range("c1:c30000")

'search duplicates in 2nd column
    For cell = 1 To delrange.Cells.Count
        If Application.CountIf(delrange, delrange(cell)) > 1 Then
            ReDim Preserve duplicate(i)
            duplicate(i) = delrange(cell).Address
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
'search duplicates in 3rd column
    For cell = 1 To delrange2.Cells.Count
        If Application.CountIf(delrange2, delrange2(cell)) > 1 Then
            ReDim Preserve duplicate(i)
            duplicate(i) = delrange2(cell).Address
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
        'add header
    shtOut.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 3).Value = _
      Array("Material Number", "Short Description", "Long Description")

'print duplicates
    For i = UBound(duplicate) To LBound(duplicate) Step -1
    shtOut.Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Value = shtIn.Range(duplicate(i)).EntireRow.Value
    x = x + 1
Next i



End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is highlighted when it errors? Also, what was changed from before when it was still working (ie. Did you add any line, etc.).

Comment: I think i got your concerns covered? :) please see my post.

Comment: Np, glad we've made your code work. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works if you run the code while the sheet that contains the data is selected.
If not, and the sheet currently selected have no value in `b1:b30000`, then this line:

```
For i = UBound(duplicate) To LBound(duplicate) Step -1
```

will produce the `Error 9` since you were not able to initialize `duplicate` variable since you only `Redim Preserve` when your `If` statement was satisfied.

To avoid the error, properly declare the variable `delrange` like this:

```
Set delrange = shtIn.Range("b1:b30")  'i assumed only that shtIn is the source sheet, change otherwise.
Set delrange2 = shtIn.Range("c1:c30")
```

and then change this line as well:

```
For i = UBound(duplicate) To LBound(duplicate) Step -1
    shtOut.Cells(x, 1).Value = shtIn.Range(duplicate(i)).Value
    x = x + 1
Next i
```

Again, i assumed that you are writing on `shtOut` and not the other way around like what you did in your code.

Comment: wow. it's work! i understand now. i think the program just confused because i don't declare it right.

Comment: yes. You can avoid it as well if you `Redim duplicate(0)` before your loop. This will eliminate the `Error 9`. however, you will get `Error 1004` in this line `shtOut.Cells(x, 1).Value = shtIn.Range(duplicate(i)).Value` since `duplicate(0)` don't contain a valid address for your `Range` object. Safest approach is to declare the variables.